# UMVUE for a Uniform distribution

Tags: estimation, unbiased-estimator, umvue, minimum-variance

How did we derive the PDF and CDF highlighted in green?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=uniform+order+statistic+density.

Comment: @learn_to_code1 You get the cdf via independence of the $X_i$ and the usual product rule for independent events. You get the density by differentiation of the cdf. The search whuber offers will have details in some of the links